# Playing audio files with discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've recently gotten back into coding and Python and wanted to check out how to make a discord bot. I've managed to send messages and do basic things, but now i can't figure out how to make it play audio in a voice channel.

I can get it to join and leave at will, but as soon as I try to play music, it's just silent. The audio file is already downloaded and it's in the same folder as my program. I do not get any errors, all i know is there is something wrong with the bot. The audio file is not just silence, I have checked. I do not know what is wrong.

What should happen is when i call for the bot and it joins my VC, it should start playing the song.

My code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['jvc'])
async def joinvc(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice_client:
        if not voice_client.is_connected():
            await voice_channel.connect()
            voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable='C:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', source='file.mp3'))
    else:
        await voice_channel.connect()
        voice_client = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable='C:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', source='file.mp3'))
```

Sorry if the code isn't great, but it was the only way I could think of without getting errors. Also I apologize if I forgot anything important or did something wrong, this is my first time using StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you install voice support ?
`pip install -U discord.py[voice]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit wrong,
Corrected code

```py
 vc=await voice_channel.connect()
 vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source="file.mp3"))
```

`voice_client` can't play files... you need to define a variable as above and then try to play

Further, It would be better if you use the exact source of file rather than relative path....

Answer (score -1):

Remember to add ffmpeg to path

```
@client.command()
async def thisisnotacommand(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    vc = await channel.connect()
    await ctx.send('Started playing: something')
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('file.mp3'), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
```

If you don't know how to add ffmpeg to path feel free to msg me `Special unit#5323`

Comment: Yeah, I did that, besides I put the whole path in as the executable.

Comment: I might try and play another file. From what I understand the after displays an error or None when the audio file stops, but for me it just waits a second and says "done None"

Comment: Try adding full path to a file